# Contando registros atualizados por dia rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como faço para contar registros atualizados por data no rails? Seguinte tenho que receber estes dados em formato de array para repassar e converter em json.
Tenho a tabela A que possui muitos da Tabela B
Através de A tenho que contar quantos registros foram atualizados por dia na tabela B.
Por exemplo dia 02/02 5 registros atualizados,
dia 03/02 9 registros,
dia 04/02 10 registros,
dia 05/02 0 registros.

Isto é para gerar um gráfico, estou apanhando para fazer, os métodos estão ficando muito grandes e acho que tem uma forma muito mais simples, alguém sabe se tem como fazer isto?

Answer (score 0):

Ficou meio vaga sua pergunta, mas creio que é isto o que vc procura:

https://github.com/ankane/groupdate